# PC hangs and restarts intermittently after Win 11 upgrade

Tags: windows-11

I have a custom desktop PC that started to hang and restart randomly after it was upgraded to windows 11.

After it hung, it also has problem starting up - hangs at some stages of restart, and needs 2 or 3 restarts to start correctly.

Mostly happens when playing games.

The PC specs list is as below:

```
    Windows 11 Pro 64-bit
    12th Gen Intel Core i7-12700KF
    Memory 32 GB G Skill 6000 MHz DDR5
    Gigabyte Technology Co. Ltd. Z690 AORUS ELITE AX (U3E1) 
    4095MB NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Ti (ZOTAC International)
    931GB Samsung SSD 980 PRO 1TB
    1863GB Crucial CT2000P2SSD8
```

What are the steps to troubleshoot this issue?

I reinstalled the NVIDIA drivers, and did disk repair once which found some invalid blocks.

Comment: It is not a Windows 11 problem either production or future build. It works properly on several machines.  Try updating all drivers including BIOS.  Take care updating any driver.  Also check Windows 11 requirements for hardware

Comment: @John I reinstalled windows 11, then installed the wifi driver for aorus 690 from the gigabyte website, then tried to enable the adapter and windows crashed immediately. Installed windows 10, installed the drivers, everything is working good up until now. Seems that Z690 wifi drivers for win 11 are not good.

Answer (score 0):

If it’s a graphics driver issue make sure that windows update isn’t automatically installing graphic drivers as they tend to overwrite your installed drivers.